# Using directives as part of angular-translate's translate-values, how to compile?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am in the process of internationalizing a website and have come across a sticking point with `angular-translate`.

Suppose I have a translationProvider for english supplying the following text:

```
"example.message": "I need a {{link}} or {{customDirectiveOutput}} to render directives in me"
"link.text": "this link"
```

I am now trying to get some HTML into those two placeholders by doing something like the following:

```
<div translate="example.message"
     translate-values="{
       link: '<a ui-sref=\'stateName\'>{{ \'link.text\' | translate }}</a>'
       customDirectiveOutput: '<span my-custom-directive=\'vm.object\'></span>'
      }">
</div>
```

Where `ui-sref` is from the `ui-router` and adds an attribute like `href="/path/to/my/state"`, and `my-custom-directive` places inner html inside the `span` sort of like this:

```
<span my-custom-directive='vm.object'>
  <span class='foo'>{{vm.object.foo}}</span> 
  <span class="bar">{{vm.object.bar}}</span>
</span>
```

The link tag I can "cheat" around by just hard-coding the `href` onto the `a` tag and that isn't so bad to duplicate the `/path/to/state`, though I'd prefer not to.

The custom directive, however, is conditional on its output so I can't just cheat the output into the `translate-values`

I've tried doing something in the controller for the page like

```
    $scope.value = vm.getValue();
    var element = $compile('<span my-custom-directive="value"></span>')($scope);        
    return element[0].outerHTML;
```

But this unfortunately creates an infinite digest loop. I feel like this is the right "path", having some JS pre-compile the fragment I need to insert into the translation, but I'm stuck as to how to accomplish that!

How can I insert angular-compiled HTML with directives attached into a translated string?